# Why use the absolute layout in the map related site?

Tags: css, position

We are building an online map (like Google Maps) and we ran into layout related problems.

When I go to the Google and Yahoo maps, I see that in their page almost all the elements are using absolute position, so they have to re-caculate the size of each element when user resizes the browser window.

So I wonder if we should leave these to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to make it more portable. Older browsers just don't handle relative layout well, i.e. correctly.

Comment: The reason I am in doubt is that these site all have some toggle button to expand the area of the map. So we have to use js to re-caculate when toggle,in this case the float is more comportable,isn't it?